# Merged data frame leaving some columns blank

Tags: r, merge, left-join

I have two data frames. The first one has a lot of country club financial data and the other contains membership data. Both of these data sets share a column called "Member_ID" which is where I am merging them together. However, the member data set contains a column titled "Alternate_ID" which I need. When I merge the two data sets, though, the "Alternate_ID" column is left with a lot of NA values.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

Finance Data:

```
Member_ID    Purchase     Purchase.Desc    Date
  1111          x               x            x
  1111          x               x            x
  1111          x               x            x
  2234          x               x            x
  2234          x               x            x
  3355          x               x            x
  3355          x               x            x
  3355          x               x            x
```

Membership Data:

```
Member_ID    Alternate_ID  
1111           9876
2234           7777
3355           5252
```

What I want:

```
Member_ID    Purchase     Purchase.Desc    Date  Alternate_ID
  1111          x               x            x     9876
  1111          x               x            x     9876
  1111          x               x            x     9876
  2234          x               x            x     7777
  2234          x               x            x     7777
  3355          x               x            x     5252
  3355          x               x            x     5252
  3355          x               x            x     5252
```

What I am getting:

```
Member_ID    Purchase     Purchase.Desc    Date  Alternate_ID
  1111          x               x            x     9876
  1111          x               x            x     -
  1111          x               x            x     -
  2234          x               x            x     7777
  2234          x               x            x     -
  3355          x               x            x     5252
  3355          x               x            x     -
  3355          x               x            x     -
```

Here is the code I am using for the merger.

```
df_finance <- transaction.csv %>% left_join(dates.csv, by = "Customer.Id")

df_finance2 <- df_finance[!is.na(df_finance$Date),]

df_finance3 <- df_finance2[!duplicated(df_finance2$Member.Id),]

colnames(df_member)[6] <- "Member.Id"

total_data <- df_member %>% left_join(df_finance3, by = "Member.Id")
```

Comment: That's strange. When I do `dplyr::left_join(df_finance, df_member)` I get what you want. Can you show your code?

Comment: Yes please show your code, otherwise we can't answer. In particular did you use `dplyr::left_join`, or `base::merge`, or something else?

Comment: I am using df_finance %>% left_join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A working version of your example:

```
# create data
df_finance <- data.frame(
    member_id = c(rep(1111, 3), rep(2234, 2), rep(3355,3)),
    descrip   = rep("x", 8))

df_membership <- data.frame(
    member_id = c(1111, 2234, 3355),
    alt_id    = c(9876, 7777, 522))

# with base R
merge(df_finance, df_membership, by="member_id", all.x=T)

  member_id descrip alt_id
1      1111       x   9876
2      1111       x   9876
3      1111       x   9876
4      2234       x   7777
5      2234       x   7777
6      3355       x    522
7      3355       x    522
8      3355       x    522

# tidyverse style
dplyr::left_join(df_finance, df_membership, by="member_id")

  member_id descrip alt_id
1      1111       x   9876
2      1111       x   9876
3      1111       x   9876
4      2234       x   7777
5      2234       x   7777
6      3355       x    522
7      3355       x    522
8      3355       x    522
```